# Securing login credentials in an iOS app bundle

Tags: ios, swift, security, credentials

I am writing an iOS app and have a dilemma. The app will be used to test the BLE protocol of devices coming off our production line. It needs to be very simple, It is a one button app that automatically connects to devices and tests commands in our protocol and gives a pass or fail result. If it passes the device id is sent to our API to be entered in our database.

My problem is I don't want the user to have to login, but I need to send a username and password to the API to log in. This means the username and password has to be included in the app. I am trying to find out the most secure way to do this. I initially thought I would include a plist in the app with the credentials, enter them in keychain, then delete the plist. However I don't believe you can delete a file included in the app bundle (I get a 513 permission error).

I have 2 questions. Is it secure to include credentials in code? Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No.
2. Use API to retrieve credentials and store to keychain. Simple call to firebase could solve this. Or use your own backend with your custom “security”.

But even obtaining via API don’t give you 100% security. Everything depends. API solution gives you flexibility and ability to support different versions with different credentials.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I will provide a one time login page and on successful login I will save the credentials to keychain. The administrator can login before the device goes to the factory floor, then the floor workers never have to log in. I have to use our API to login and and its not clear to me how I can retrieve credentials from our API and still securely provide credentials in the app bundle to do that. If I don't receive a better answer shortly I will mark this as correct.